# React router warning

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react router and getting this warning:

```
[react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored.
```

Though everything works properly I still can't get out of this warning. Can anybody tell what can cause such warning?

here's an example of my router

```
render () {
return (
  <div>
    <Router history={this.history}>
      <Route path='/' component={PageLanding} />
      <Route path='/test' onEnter={CheckUser.CheckUser} component={PageTest} />
      <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Router>
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: What version of [tag:react-router] are you using? Also, please provide your router code in your question.

Comment: the version is 3.0.0

Comment: Okay, you're still not providing your Routing in your question though. Please add that.

Comment: ah, my bad, sorry. I edited my question

Comment: Are you putting your router inside a `Component` that gets re-rendered? Try putting a `console.log` in that `render()` method and check if it gets printed twice. I usually create the `<Router>` element as a global constant, so it only gets created once

Comment: yes it's rendering twice. Is there another way of solving it, not just creating as global constant?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router "^3.0.2" use following structure

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={mainComponentName} />
    <Route path='/componentRefName' component={componentName} />
    <Route path='/componentRefName' component={componentName} />
</Router>,
```

If you are using react-router "4.0" use following structure

```
<HashRouter>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={mainComponentName} ></Route>
        <Route path="/componentRefName" component={componentName}></Route>
        <Route path="/componentRefName" component={componentName}></Route>
    </div>
</HashRouter>
```